# Magento 2 doesn't resolve my own Repository Interface in the custom module

Tags: magento2, module, repository

I'm trying to create a custom module for Magento 2. when I try to inject the ThreadRepositoryInterface into the controller constructor the code fails.

This is the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Mycompany\Tickets\Api\ThreadRepositoryInterface in /var/www/html2/magento2.local/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 73
```

this is the structure of the module:

```
.
├── Api
│   ├── AttachmentRepositoryInterface.php
│   ├── CategoryRepositoryInterface.php
│   ├── Data
│   │   ├── AttachmentInterface.php
│   │   ├── AttachmentSearchResultsInterface.php
│   │   ├── CategoryInterface.php
│   │   ├── CategorySearchResultsInterface.php
│   │   ├── StatusInterface.php
│   │   ├── StatusSearchResultsInterface.php
│   │   ├── ThreadInterface.php
│   │   ├── ThreadSearchResultsInterface.php
│   │   ├── TicketsInterface.php
│   │   └── TicketsSearchResultsInterface.php
│   ├── StatusRepositoryInterface.php
│   ├── ThreadRepositoryInterface.php
│   └── TicketsRepositoryInterface.php
├── Block
│   ├── Create
│   │   └── Form.php
│   ├── Index
│   │   └── Tickets.php
│   └── Reply
│       └── Index.php
├── composer.json
├── Controller
│   ├── Create
│   │   └── Index.php
│   ├── Index
│   │   ├── Fastlink.php
│   │   └── Index.php
│   └── Reply
│       └── Index.php
├── etc
│   ├── acl.xml
│   ├── adminhtml
│   │   ├── menu.xml
│   │   ├── routes.xml
│   │   └── system.xml
│   ├── config.xml
│   ├── di.xml
│   ├── email_templates.xml
│   ├── frontend
│   │   └── routes.xml
│   ├── module.xml
│   └── webapi.xml
├── Helper
│   ├── AbstractData.php
│   └── Data.php
├── LICENSE.txt
├── Model
│   ├── Attachment
│   │   └── DataProvider.php
│   ├── Attachment.php
│   ├── AttachmentRepository.php
│   ├── Category
│   │   └── DataProvider.php
│   ├── Category.php
│   ├── CategoryRepository.php
│   ├── Config
│   │   └── Source
│   │       └── Tickets
│   │           └── Status.php
│   ├── ResourceModel
│   │   ├── Attachment
│   │   │   └── Collection.php
│   │   ├── Attachment.php
│   │   ├── Category
│   │   │   └── Collection.php
│   │   ├── Category.php
│   │   ├── Status
│   │   │   └── Collection.php
│   │   ├── Status.php
│   │   ├── Thread
│   │   │   └── Collection.php
│   │   ├── Thread.php
│   │   ├── Tickets
│   │   │   └── Collection.php
│   │   └── Tickets.php
│   ├── Sendmail.php
│   ├── Status
│   │   └── DataProvider.php
│   ├── Status.php
│   ├── StatusRepository.php
│   ├── Thread
│   │   └── DataProvider.php
│   ├── Thread.php
│   ├── ThreadRepository.php
│   ├── Tickets
│   │   └── DataProvider.php
│   ├── Tickets.php
│   ├── TicketsRepository.php
│   └── TicketsSearchResult.php
├── registration.php
├── Setup
│   ├── InstallData.php
│   └── InstallSchema.php
└── view
    └── frontend
        ├── email
        │   └── ticket_new.html
        ├── layout
        │   ├── customer_account.xml
        │   ├── tickets_create_index.xml
        │   ├── tickets_index_fastlink.xml
        │   ├── tickets_index_index.xml
        │   └── tickets_reply_index.xml
        └── templates
            ├── form
            │   ├── register.phtml
            │   └── reply.phtml
            └── list.phtml

36 directories, 76 files
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you have created your own module/template and the Resolver doesn't resolve one of your Api interface you have to add the specific preference in the di.xml file located into your module.

For instance:

```
<preference for="Yourcompany\Yourmodule\Api\Data\YourInterface" type="Yourcompany\Yourmodule\Model\Yourmodel"/>
```

then you have to execute the shell command to clean up your magento cache:

```
rm -rf var/di var/generation pub/static/frontend var/view_preprocessed var/page_cache/ var/cache/
```

or simply:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

and now the interface will be resolved!